# Is it possible to exclude an item from a pageBlock re-render?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a series of checkboxes within a pageBlock. For design reasons, I'd like to keep the checkboxes checked when the pageBlock is re-rendered. Is this possible?

Comment: You can enclose your components in different containers (e.g. pageblocksection) and rerender only the block sections you want to rerender and not the checkbox.

Comment: Is it possible to rerender html component ids? Or is the rerender attribute limited to apex block component ids?

Comment: @AlexBrigham - you can wrap html components in a output panel with a layout="inline" for a span instead of layout="block" for a div

Comment: @AlexBrigham the rules is "Visualforce cannot re-render any element that is not managed by the view state." ... you can use apex:outputPanel to resolve your issues instead of div. This post might be helpful http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13348/rerender-standard-html-element-from-visualforce-component