# actionpoller to update number on vfpage

Tags: apex, actionregion, actionpoller

I am using action poller to update a number on the vf page.

```
<div id='notification'>{!taskSize}</div>
```

actionpoller code:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!actionItemsFiltered}" name="popup"/>
            <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:actionPoller action="{!actionItemsFiltered}" reRender="notification" interval="5"/>
            </apex:actionRegion>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered=""/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!showPopup}" >
                <apex:dataTable value="{!taskReturnList}" var="task" id="theTable" styleClass="tableClass">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">Task</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputText value="{!task.Subject}" style="font-weight:800"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:dataTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

Controller method:

```
global static pagereference actionItemsFiltered()
    {
        taskReturnList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Subject, Type FROM Task WHERE type IN ('anurag', 'Repeat CST') LIMIT 50000];
        taskSize = taskReturnList.size();
        showPopup = true;
        system.debug('1size:'+taskSize);
        return null;    
    }
```

I set the interval in actionpoller for 5 sec. I can see debug logs for every 5 sec by which i can say that the method is executing everytime, but the counter on page is not changing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: add to vf: <apex:outputText value="task: {!taskSize}" id="notification"/> and 
to apex: public Integer getTaskSize() {return taskSize;}

Comment: Cool this worked, but why can't i achieve the same when the outputtext is in div tag as i have in my code?

Comment: [read this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13348/rerender-standard-html-element-from-visualforce-component)

Comment: <apex:outputpanel id="notification">
 <apex:outputText value="task: {!taskSize}"/>
 //more elements
</apex:outputpanel>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your div line with

```
<apex:outputpanel id="notification">{!taskSize}</apex:outputpanel>
```

Comment: It works this way, but couldnt i get the same with div?

Comment: no it can't be achieved with only div tag. salesforce require apex component when you put that in rerender attribute.